# Hibernate: @OneToMany, avoid multiple SELECTs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Consider an example where a person can have a lot of cars. That's why we are using @OneToMany annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public Person() {
    }

    // Getters setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person owner;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public Car() {
    }

    // Getters setters
```

Persistence and everything works fine, but I would like to change something to fit my needs. When the program starts I want all persons to be loaded in memory, let's say in a `List<Person>`. So, I do this:

```
List<Person> persons = session.createQuery("from Person", Person.class).list();
```

But, as it makes sense, Hibernate loads the cars too. **Is there a way to stop it from doing that?**

The reason of that is because it is faster to do something like the following:

```
List<Person> persons = loadAllPersonsFromDatabase();
List<Car> allCars = loadAllCarsFromDatabase();
for (Person p : persons)
{
    List<Car> carsOfThisPerson = findCarsOfThisPerson(allCars,p);
    p.setCars(carsOfThisPerson);
}
```

since I want everything in memory.

I know that loading all records of a database in memory is not a common practice, and the reason of that is because the one is a database and the other is a memory. However, my environment is a desktop connection, where queries are kind of slow (since the database is standalone) and I'm sure that these records will never be that many that will cause an `OutOfMemoryError`.

I think it is also important to mention that changing `FetchType.EAGER` to `FetchType.LAZY` will not work me. It will be the same since after I load the data, I call the `getCars()` for all persons.

@crizis in comments has a good point. The reason I don't simply delete the relationship (do `@Transient List<Car> cars`) of those two (Person,Car), is because I want to have the other functionalities persistence offers. I mean, if I do this:

```
Car car = getCarByPerson("John");
car.setDescription("John");
```

I will be able to save this car by:

```
hibernateSession.save(john);
```

and not by: `hibernateSession.save(car);`

Also, in case I delete John, I want all his cars to be deleted as well (that's where `CASCADE` comes in), without me being forced to:

```
for (Car c : john.getCars())
    hibernateSession.delete(c);
```

or whatever.

Comment: Please check this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915829/how-do-i-fetch-only-parent-records-which-has-onetomany-relation-with-2-other-ta

Comment: So, you want `Person.cars` to get populated but not `Car.owner`? Why not simply make the association unidirectional and put `@JoinColumn @Fetch(JOIN)` on `Person.cars`? That way, your query will load everything into memory just like you wanted

Comment: @crizzis I want persons to be populated, but when I will hit `person.getCars()`, the list will be empty. Then I will fill these car lists by my self, manually.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't follow. If you don't want JPA to manage the `Person.cars` property, why did you make it a side of the association in the first place? Just mark it as `@Transient`

Comment: @crizzis I updated my question in order to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments and searching on web, I found out that using `FetchMode.SELECT` will do exactly what I want and it is exactly what I was looking for. I changed:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

and indeed it does only 2 selects.

Answer (score -1):

Create a memory dump and analyze that to see what is using all that memory. Maybe you just need to increase the max heap size.
You could also make it lazy and use `Hibernate.initialize` on the cars collection. That way, I even think its possible to use a fetch mode like e.g. SUBSELECT.
If nothing helps, I can recommend using Blaze-Persistence Entity Views to reduce loaded state to a minimum and use a SUBSELECT fetch strategy for sure.